# How to get older updates for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for C++ desktop development. My company writes libraries for other developers, and because some customers are understandably loathe to upgrade once they settle on a development platform, we need to support developers at various update (née "service pack") levels.

It seems that Microsoft is (equally understandably) pushing everyone to get all the service packs when they get any, since when I [ask to download Update 1 here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797915/en-us), it pushes me to Update 3, which includes Updates 1 & 2.

I have now archived Update 3 (using the /layout flag on the installer), but I don't see a way to get just Update 1 or Update 2, and yet that is exactly what I need. How can I get these updates?

Comment: This is really a question for Microsoft.

Comment: I have searched the dickens out of it and can't find it. I was hoping for a backdoor (e.g., "edit the URL to have '&Ver=2' on the end"), an unofficial "you can't do that," or something else someone may have found about this issue. Perhaps it belongs on superuser.com instead of here since it is more of a configuration issue?

Comment: There's a time to search, and a time to go ask.

Comment: There has been a new wind blowing at Microsoft for the past two years.  They switched to an agile rapidly release cycle, keeping up with the joneses.  The old service pack approach is history.  The only real way to deal with this is just give in, resistance is futile.  If your customer refuse to work along then it's your burden to keep copies of the installer.  Hope you didn't find out too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answer from Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/be3dd1de-ce07-4a43-b319-3fe48f0875d8/how-to-get-older-updates-service-packs-for-visual-studio-2012):

> There is no longer update 1 and 2 from official site, I cannot provide
>   a link for you either. Actually I would recommend your customer update
>   their VS to avoid possible development problems. There are logs of
>   fixes for VS on Update 3.

Comment: Did you finally found a download location? I need the vs2012.2 update..

Comment: No. I did download Update 3 locally, so we can get to that version as needed, and we setup a plan to download and store future versions also.